# How do I properly pass these function values in C++

Tags: c++, function

I am trying to write a program using functions that calculates county tax, sales tax, adds them together, and outputs them in main. I have also made a printData function so I could output everything at once but i'm confused on how to use it, because of an initialization error in run time. I am not very good with function and was hoping I could get some help.

Here is my written code: (updated)

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void calcCounty(double &TotalSales, double &CountySalesTax);
void calcState(double &TotalSales, double &StateSalesTax);
void calcTotal(double &TotalSales, double &CountySalesTax, double &StateSalesTax);
void printData(double &TotalSales, double &CountySalesTax, double &StateSalesTax);

double TotalSales;
double CountySalesTax;
double StateSalesTax;

int main()
{

    cout << "Tax Calculation program" << endl;
    cin >> TotalSales;
    printData(TotalSales, CountySalesTax, StateSalesTax);
    cout << TotalSales << CountySalesTax << StateSalesTax;
    return 0;
}

void calcCounty(double &TotalSales, double &CountySalesTax)
{
    CountySalesTax = TotalSales * 0.4;
}

void calcState(double &TotalSales, double &StateSalesTax)
{
    StateSalesTax = TotalSales * 0.2;
}

void calcTotal(double &TotalSales, double &CountySalesTax, double &StateSalesTax)
{
    TotalSales = CountySalesTax + StateSalesTax;
}

void printData(double &TotalSales, double &CountySalesTax, double &StateSalesTax)
{
    cout << TotalSales, CountySalesTax, StateSalesTax;
}
```

Comment: Having functions returning values is easier to understand

Comment: But you never call your functions?

Comment: You also need to read up on the comma operator, because the output in `printData` will not be what you expect.

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize your variables first (the ones you need).

For example, this function:

```
void calcCounty(double &TotalSales, double &CountySalesTax)
{
    CountySalesTax = TotalSales * 0.4;
}
```

should have `TotalSales` initialized before been called.

As suggested by the comments, you also need to call the functions at some point.

Moreover, the printing should be done like this in your case:

`cout << TotalSales << ", " << CountySalesTax << ", " << StateSalesTax;`

First, I would suggest you to read this example:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

/*
 * Write a program, which will declare two variables, 'a' and 'b'.
 * They will be initialized with the values 10 and 100, respectively.
 * Write a function 'int find_min(int a, int b)`, which will find
 * which of the given parameters is less and will return it.
 *
 * Then, write `void find_min_no_return(int a, int b, int& min)`,
 * which will do the same job as `find_min()`, but with no return
 * statement.
 */

int find_min(int a, int b) {
  if(a < b) {
    return a;
  }
  else {
    return b;
  }
}

/*
 * 'min' is passed by reference because it is
 * going to be modified. 'a' and 'b' are passed
 * by value.
 */
void find_min_no_return(int a, int b, int& min) {
  if(a < b) {
    min = a;
  }
  else {
    min = b;
  }
}

int main() {
  int a = 10;
  int b = 100;

  int min;

  min = find_min(a, b);
  cout << "min of first function called = " << min << endl;

  find_min_no_return(a, b, min);
  cout << "min of second function called = " << min << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

and then solve your problem.

Comment: i'm still really lost. i've spent so much time trying to understand this but i'm still confused. apparently got rid of the initilization error. I tried adding this function call in main but get nothing back: printData(TotalSales, CountySalesTax, StateSalesTax);

Comment: I want you @VishantKhunti to modify your code and update your question, after you have read my example.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you rather return a value from your functions?

```
double calcCounty(double& totalSales) {
return totalSales * 0.4;
}
```

Then in your main do:

```
countySalesTax = calcCounty(totalSales);
```